# How do you play an animation with code?

Tags: python, animation

How to make, with a script, Blender play the current animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script that plays an animation is something like this:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```

In the future, if you want to use python to do something, you can make it easier by activating **Python Tooltips**, which you can do by going to *Edit >> Preferences >> Interface >> Python Tooltips*. You can see Python Tooltips in action by hovering over a button like the Play Animation button.

Comment: Um... hi, can you help me? Can you please share the code if there are many animations and I want to play a specific one?